# Bundler error with passenger-install-nginx-module on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

I am installing passenger + nginx on `ubuntu 14.04` & `ruby 2.2.4`. There are `bundler` errors with `passenger-install-nginx-module`

```
  $passenger-install-nginx-module
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:45:in `full_gem_path': uninitialized constant Bundler::Plugin::API::Source (NameError)
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:144:in `block in full_require_paths'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:143:in `map'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:143:in `full_require_paths'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:76:in `contains_requirable_file?'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:949:in `block in find_in_unresolved'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:949:in `each'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:949:in `find_all'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:949:in `find_in_unresolved'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:74:in `require'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/plugin/api/source.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:45:in `full_gem_path'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:144:in `block in full_require_paths'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:143:in `map'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:143:in `full_require_paths'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1370:in `add_self_to_load_path'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1283:in `activate'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in `block in gem'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:66:in `synchronize'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:66:in `gem'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/passenger-install-nginx-module:22:in `<main>'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
            from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Before that, `gem passenger (v5.0.30)` and `rails 4.2.0` have been installed. What causes the error?

Comment: try updating your bundler using `gem update bundler`

Comment: Returns `Nothing to update`. bundler version is 1.13.1 and it is the latest version.

Comment: Try to remove .rvm and .bundle files for this user and reinstall rails. It works for me, few hours ago I was facing same error

Comment: After removing `gem rails`, then `passenger-install-nginx-module` starts to work. Odd, isn't it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had the same problem,

What I did:

```
gem uninstall bundler -v1.13.1
```

(or `gem uninstall bundler -v1.13`)

Then

```
gem install bundler -v 1.12
```

Then `passenger-install-apache2-module` works.

---

Suggestions here:

- https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/6203
- https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/6066

Answer (score 5):

Check if you have the right version of RubyGems

`$ gem -v`

2.6.5 (or superior)

---

If you have not, upgrade your RubyGems:

`$ gem update --system`

If you can't use `sudo` like this:

`$ sudo gem update --system`

---

Now check you have the last bundler version:

`$ bundle -v`

Bundler version 1.13.0 (or superior)

---

If you have not, upgrade your Bundler:

`$ gem install bundler`