# Rails 5 'full_gem_path' : uninitialized constant Bundler

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

> Edit: I found the answer [here](http://kuro-sean-blog.logdown.com/posts/901359-cant-not-new-a-rails-app-with-rails-new-command) right after I finished my post.

Orirginal Post:

I just upgraded from Mac Yosemite (10.10.5) to El Sierra (10.12)

I can create a rails project fine via
`rails new <name>`

However, when I go into the newly created project folder, running any rails commands

> e.g. `rails -v` or `rails s`

Results in this stack trace:

[image]

BUT, when I exit from the project folder, I can continue to run rails commands without issue such as

> e.g. `rails -v` and `rails new <name>`

Below are my versions if it helps any:

[image]

Please help!

Comment: I posted my solution, is the right solution. ;)

Comment: @WaKeMaTTa Do you want to link it here?

Comment: 1 moderator deleted my post, because i posted the same solution in 2 questions. =( . Here is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528942/bundler-error-with-passenger-install-nginx-module-on-ubuntu-14-04/39870426#39870426

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Check if your bundler version is v1.13 (with `bundler -v`). If it is indeed v1.13, then you can remove v1.13 and install v1.12 to fix this problem:
>
> 1. `sudo gem uninstall bundler -v1.13.1` OR `gem uninstall bundler`
> 2. THEN `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin bundler -v 1.12`
>
> if you use rvm you can remove bundler follow this way
>
> `rm -rf ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p647/gems/bundler-1.13.1`

Taken from:

http://kuro-sean-blog.logdown.com/posts/901359-cant-not-new-a-rails-app-with-rails-new-command

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone comes to this question the way I did, I was getting this issue when trying to install rspec.  I was able to install it using bundle's exec command:

```
 bundle exec rails generate rspec:install
```

Not sure if this would also solve the OP's question.